# How to use ng-blur function in angularjs-dropdown-multiselect directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angularjs-dropdown-multiselect Directive. I want to call a function after the selection process. I am not able to use ng-blur function inside this directive. Please help me out

Following is my code

```
<div class="multiselectDropDown" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
   disabled="disabled" options="resultsWithInfo" selected- 
   model="selected_baselines"
   extra-settings="selected_baseline_settings" translation- 
   texts="selected_baselines_customTexts" ng-blur="addUsers()">
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code, What you have tried and where is the problem

Comment: @Shridhar Acharya  you can use `onItemSelect` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call onSelectionChanged callback with "events" attribute. Below is the code sample

HTML

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" events="onChange" selected-model="example1model">
```

Controller

```
$scope.onChange = {
  onSelectionChanged : function () {
    alert("trigger me")
  }
}
```

Comment: This is fine if the event should happen on select, but events where the entire dropdown is closed still remain untenable.  For example, when user selects 5 things in dropdown, we want to trigger event when he is done and has closed dropdown.  Not on each seleciton or deselection...